# Mobile Device Detect Orientation Locked in javascript / HTML5

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, html

I have an html5 web game I am developing that requires mobile devices to be in landscape mode.
Because I cannot force rotation on certain devices/browsers (Safari), to force landscape, I am simply rotating my html content using the CSS below.

The problem I have, is that on mobile devices (iPhone) if the user has their device locked in Portrait Mode, it messes with the experience (the browser frame will not rotate to match its landscape contents). 
I need to display a message to let them know they need to unlock the devices Portrait Lock feature. I have not been able to determine if any javascript method exists to detect if their mobile device is explicitly locked into portrait mode. I found old posts (2015) that say it was not possible, but I am hoping feature support has improved. I did review the Screen Orientations API, however default orientation is not the same as explicit locked orientation.

My CSS to force landscape:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and orientation:portrait) {
    body {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tony, what happens when the device orientation is locked? Does it `landscape` the content into the portrait? I am wondering if there is a known behavior you could test for it. e.g. an element size etc.

Comment: The browser page content is oriented to be landscape, making it apparent to the user to rotate their device to be readable, if the iPhone is locked, the safari browser (browser bar and frame) stays in portrait mode so it is 90% our of sync with the page content / game UI.

Comment: Ok, so I am thinking that maybe you need to test is an element is visible (one that should be visible, but is hidden via overflow where the browser bar is.)

Comment: That sounds like it could work, however my page is responsive so all the elements in my page are still visible (just way too small for best experience).
I thought I could check the screen height/width ratio when the user rotates the device, however I read a post that indicated if the phone orientation is locked, that a physical rotation will not fire any rotation events.

Comment: Ok, but that works also. Test the computed style size. of a known elemement for the given device. For example elementX.width === x for iPhone XS. Here is documentation for getting computed styles (you will need this to get final render size) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle